# Maven: Only want to run profile if doing a build on the parent pom

Tags: maven-2, maven

I'm using Maven 3.0.3.  I have a project that inherits from a parent …

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myco.util.ant</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-framework</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Myco Selenium Utils</name>
    <parent>
            <groupId>com.nna</groupId>
            <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <relativePath>../parent</relativePath>
    </parent>
```

In my parent pom I have the below profile.  However, I only want this profile to be active if someone is doing a build on the parent pom, as opposed to one of its children.  Does anyone know how I can adjust the below so that it won't be activated if someone is doing a build of a child project?

```
            <profile>
                    <id>deploy-snapshot</id>
                    <build>
                            <plugins>
                                    <plugin>
                                            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                                            <version>1.6</version>
                                            <executions>
                                                    <execution>
                                                            <phase>deploy</phase>
                                                            <configuration>
                                                                    <target>
                                                                            <condition property="is-release">
                                                                                    <not>
                                                                                            <contains string="${project.version}" substring="SNAPSHOT" />
                                                                                    </not>
                                                                            </condition>
                                                                            <fail if="is-release" message="You can only deploy snapshot versions of this project." />
                                                                    </target>
                                                            </configuration>
                                                            <goals>
                                                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                                            </goals>
                                                    </execution>
                                            </executions>
                                    </plugin>
                            </plugins>
                    </build>
                    <activation>
                            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
                    </activation>
            </profile>
```

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 0):

You could try activating it by the presence/absence of a file or directory. You can find an [example in the Sonatype Maven book](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/profiles-sect-activation.html#profiles-sect-activation-config). Note that there's a difference between "current working directory" and "`${project.basedir}`", and the differences are slightly different between Maven 2 and Maven 3, if that matters to you.

Comment: Thanks for the idea about profile activation based on presence of a file, but my parent project only has a pom.xml file and a target directory, not enough (based on those files alone) to distinguish it from child projects.  Any other thoughts? -

Comment: @Dave. You can always add directory ( and/or file ) even to a `pom` project.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation, I wanted to run a profile in a subproject by default but not when build from the top level, and at the same time give the option to run it from the top project as well.

I used the `user.dir` property for that in combination of Ryan's reference.

in *integration* project's pom:

```
    <profile>
        <id>continuous-integration</id>
        <!-- Two ways of activating this profile -->
        <activation>
            <!-- Run the build from the top with param -DfullTest -->
            <property>
                <name>fullTest</name>
            </property>
            <!-- Run the build from the integration directory -->
            <file>
                <missing>${user.dir}/integration</missing>
            </file>
        </activation>
    ...
    <profile>
```

If needs to be disabled just change the `<missing/>` for a `<exists/>`.